# Grep ping output to only show latency using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, grep

From this:

```
PING google.com (74.125.68.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sc-in-f138.1e100.net (74.125.68.138): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=76.8 ms
64 bytes from sc-in-f138.1e100.net (74.125.68.138): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=86.8 ms
```

I need to separate this part using javascript:

```
76.8
86.8
```

So far I came up with this:

```
'([0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9] ms|[0-9][0-9].[0-9] ms|[0-9].[0-9] ms)'
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly when latency reaches more than 2 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
/time=(\d+(\.\d+)?) ms$/  // 1: one digit or more
       \_/\______/        // 2: optionally followed by a dot and one digit or more
        1     2           // $: end of input
```

```js
var ping =
  "64 bytes from sc-in-f138.1e100.net (74.125.68.138): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=76.8 ms";

var time = Number(ping.match(/time=(\d+(\.\d+)?) ms$/)[1]);

console.log(time);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this nice explanation. I really should spend some time learning regex.

Comment: Glad to help! The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a pretty good start.

Comment: I posted a new question thats a bit related to this. If you are interested can you please have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936419/capturing-websocketd-output-with-smoothie-charts